# JS Calculating and constantly showing result

Tags: javascript, html

I have a starting value 1000. 
On button FIGHT (which already has onclikc) it needs to do 1000-20 and shows in html 980, another click 960..

```js
function damagec() {
    var a = 500;
    var b = a/20;
    document.getElementById('resultl').innerHTML = b;
    document.getElementById('resultl').style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById('resultlc').innerHTML = b;
    document.getElementById('resultlc').style.color = 'green';
}
```

```html
<div class="wall">
    <p id="wallvalue">1000</p>
</div>
<button onclick="damagec()"><b>FIGHT</b></button>
```

Comment: So store the value in a variable and subtract from it. What have you tried?

Comment: What's the point of `var a = 500;` and why are you dividing?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it was a stupid code of mine. As a result i had "NaN".

Comment: @J08691 not finished yet, it shoud take a value from somewhere. Doing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.damagec = function(){
    var label = document.getElementById('wallvalue');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) - 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="wall">
    <p id="wallvalue">1000</p>
</div>
<BUTTON onclick="damagec()"><b>FIGHT</b></BUTTON>
```

You can store the value from the element and subtract whatever value you want from it before assigning it back to the element

```
var label = document.getElementById('wallvalue');
label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) - 20;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Didn't know about this one a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="wall">
    <p id="wallvalue">1000</p>
</div>
<BUTTON onclick="damagec()"><b>FIGHT</b></BUTTON>


<script>

function damagec(){
 
 var wallVal = document.getElementById('wallvalue').innerHTML;
 wallVal = wallVal - 20;
 document.getElementById('wallvalue').innerHTML = wallVal;

}

</script>
```